# HK2 Custom annotation Annotation disallowed on Constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, constructor-injection, hk2

Using HK2 injection framework i developed a custom annotation for injecting my custom object inside my classes.

All works fine if i annotate my objects as class variables:

```
public class MyClass {
    @MyCustomAnnotation
    MyType obj1

    @MyCustomAnnotation
    MyType obj2

     ...
```

Now i need to inject my objects as constructor parameters ie:

```
public class MyClass {

    MyType obj1        
    MyType obj2

    @MyCustomAnnotation
    public MyClass(MyType obj1, MyType obj2){
        this.obj1 = obj1;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }
     ...
```

In my injection resolver i overrided the:

```
@Override
public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
    return true;
}
```

in order to return true.

The problem is when i try to build my project it catches an error telling:

```
"The annotation MyCustomAnnotation is disallowed for this location"
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Sounds like an annotation definition problem. Make sure you have the [`ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) in the `@Target`. Did you not have a compiler error (in your IDE) before trying to build?

Comment: oh...yes.. you're right... can i specify just one target? what if i want the annotation to work both with variable AND constructor?

Comment: `@Target({.. , ... , ... })` :-)

Comment: great! it works... really helpful as always!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like an annotation definition problem. The `@Target` on the annotation definition defines where the annotation is allowed. The allowed targets are in the [`ElementType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) enum set.

> `ANNOTATION_TYPE`, `CONSTRUCTOR`, `FIELD`, `LOCAL_VARIABLE`, `METHOD`, `PACKAGE`, `PARAMETER`, `TYPE`

In order to able to target a constructor, you need to add `CONSTRUCTOR` to the `@Target`. You can have more than one target. For example

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

**See Also:**

- [Javadoc for `@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html)